# How to generate a stacktrace of method that is called

Tags: c#, reflection

I call a method of another c# assembly, which returns true or false.

Now I want to find out if the method itself calls another method to generate the return value or simply returns true or false because it's hardcoded.

I already solved the problem by looking into the IL code, but but i'm wondering if there is an more generic way to do this by stacktrace?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  To get a useful stack trace you have to write code inside the method that is called.  No point in writing it when you need to find it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack will show you the calls that lead to the current line, but not a complete history. In other words, you can only see whether a method was called *while* it is being called. After it returns from a method, the information about what happened inside is lost.

So if you own this method that may or may not be called, or any other methods it would trigger (via event subscription for example), you would be able to place [StackFrame.GetFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in one of them and see where it was coming from. Otherwise, I think the only way to do it would be to duplicate the logic inside the method to work out whether it would have been called.

Comment: Don't forget compiler optimizations when compiled in Release Mode, the stackframe can be 'incomplete'.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. What do you mean by duplicating the logic? I don't want to build an interpreter for c# or IL. If possible I wouldn't want to change the underlying code, because my program should only generate a List for a wiki.

Comment: @Netbus I mean manually writing a skeleton of the method you're calling so you know whether it would have reached the branch where it calls the second method.

Answer (score 1):

Use a decompiler like DotPeek or JustDecompile.

http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx

Don't waste time on IL (unless you **really** have lots of time)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that is not possible because other assembly can be just a .dll which u might have referenced in your project.

If you have ample of time you may try unethical way of breaking the .dll which will let you explore all the source code.

Comment: I'm not looking to start an argument, but there's nothing unethical about using a decompiler.  It's no different than buying a food product you like, eating it, and deciding you want to make your own by looking at the ingredients listed on the package. :)

Comment: @codenoire You know better dude. If breaking into the unauthorized code without the owners permission is not unethical. Then something is really wrong with you.

Comment: @PrakashVishwakarma It's quite a stretch to say that looking at the inner workings of a product is unethical. It's also "unauthorized" to break a warranty seal with a screwdriver.